# finding a pair of integers in a sorted array which sum to K

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

Given a sorted array of integers, how can we find a pair of integers that sum to K?

e.g. `array = 1,3,5,6,10`, `K = 6`, the answer is 1 and 5.

Time complexity should be minimized.

Comment: sounds a lot like this blog post that's been making the rounds today: http://www.codingatwork.com/2011/07/array-sum/

Comment: Does the academic policy of your university and the policy of your professor allow you to ask people on the internet to answer your homework questions?

Comment: This question has been asked a million times before..even on here. Please at least do a google search before posting a question.As far as the solution goes..to minimize time use a hashtable. To minimize space..sort the array, have two pointers each pointing to one end and increment and decrement them as required.

Comment: You're saying you have a sorted array. But the example array isn't sorted. Which is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to look at this blog post:

http://www.codingatwork.com/2011/07/array-sum/

My approach would be to do a binary search of the list for `K/2`, then walk one variable `a` left and another variable `b` right trying to find a solution `a+b=K`.

The idea would be to start `a` at the largest number less than or equal to `K/2` and start `b` at the smallest number greater than `a`. Again, use a binary search to find `a` and let `b` be the next element in the array. Then

- If `a+b = K`, then `return (a,b)`.
- If `a+b < K`, then move `b` to the right one position.
- If `a+b > K`, then move `a` to the left one position.

Of course, you can skip the binary search and just start `a` at the beginning of the array and `b` at the end of the array, and then do

- If `a+b = K`, then `return (a,b)`.
- If `a+b < K`, then move `a` to the right one position.
- If `a+b > K`, then move `b` to the left one position.

This is probably faster.

Answer (score 4):

There is a linear (O(n)) solution.

Take a hashtable and while iterating through the array check if the current element is already in the hashtable - if so then you've found the answer. Otherwise insert the number which is equal to K minus the current element. Works for non sorted array, btw.

```
int[] ar = new int[] { 1, 4, 3, 5 };
int K = 6;

HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
foreach (int a in ar)
{
    if (set.Contains(a))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + ", " + (K - a));
        break;
    }

    set.Add(K - a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findpairzero(arr) {
 let left = 0;
 let right = arr.length - 1;

 while (left < right) {
 if (arr[left] + arr[right] === 0) {
  return [arr[left], arr[right]];
  } else if (arr[left] + arr[right] > 0) {
  right--;
  } else {
  left++;
 }
}
}

console.log(findpairzero([-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 5]));
```